# OpenProcess for PID owned by "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

Tags: .net, winapi

I am trying to open a process handle in C# using the OpenProcess function as follows:

```
IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(0x410, false, pid);
```

where `pid` is the process ID of the process I would like to open.

When called on a PID whose user is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" (on Vista x64), the above call fails, with an "Access Denied" error.

**How do I get a handle of such a process?**

What makes me think this is at all possible is that the .NET `System.Diagnostics.Process` class seems to be able to operate on such processes. For example, `Process.ProcessName` works fine on such processes. Under the hood, it calls `Process.MainModule.ModuleName`, which ultimately calls `OpenProcess` in exactly the same way I do. However, `System.Diagnostics` doesn't get the "Access Denied" error whereas I do.

Curiously, anything that attempts to get the handle of the process into my application also throws the exception. For example, `Process.Handle` and `Process.MainModule` both throw an "Access Denied" error, despite the fact that `Process.MainModule` clearly succeeds when called indirectly through `Process.ProcessName`.

**Does `System.Diagnostics` operate under some sort of raised privileges? How can I raise the privileges of my application to be able to do the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get a handle of such a process?
>   How can I raise the privileges of my application to be able to do the same?

Apparently the application needs to give itself the `SeDebugPrivilege`: [How To Use the SeDebugPrivilege to Acquire Any Process Handle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185215)

However it's not a great idea for a general-purpose app to rely on this because [SeDebugPrivilege is equivalent to administrator privileges](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/14/8080140.aspx) (security-wise).

I'm still not sure how exactly `System.Diagnostics` exposes `Process.ProcessName` without requiring the `SeDebugPrivilege`, but then I know next to nothing about the code security features of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Process name and a few other things don't require privileges to get.

Anyway, the reason you need SeDebugPrivilege is that with most arguments to OpenProcess you can compromise the machine's security if opening a SYSTEM process.

See WriteProcessMemory for the obvious reason.

Furthermore, .NET processes are not special to the kernel. If you can declare OpenProcess you have all the privileges of System.Diagnostics.Process.

Comment: Take a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880(VS.85).aspx for PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION. Your current code asks for PROCESS_VM_READ which you're *definitely* not going to get under Vista+ for stuff you don't own

Comment: Thanks for this. You say process name does not require privileges to get. However the only way I found of getting the name is OpenProcess, which fails on SYSTEM-owned pids due to privilege issues. Could you please show how to get the name with WinAPI calls without special privileges? I'll accept that as the answer.